# MongoError: Transaction numbers are only allowed on a replica set member or mongos

Tags: javascript, mongodb, docker, moongose

Ayuda, intento trabajar `NodeJS y MongoDB` desde `Docker`, se conecta normal, pero no puede crear ninguna `collection`

```
MONGO_URI="mongodb://localhost:27017/compras"
```

```
let db = String(process.env.MONGO_URI);
mongoose
  .connect(db, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
  })
  .then((db) => console.log("Database is connected"))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const saveUser(users){
    const session = await mongoose.startSession();
    try{
        await session.startTransaction();
        let user = new User({...users});
        user.save()
        await session.commitTransaction();
        session.endSession();
    }catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        await session.abortTransaction();
        session.endSession();
        return statusResponse.error(err)
    }
}
```

**Docker**

en docker no tengo ninguna configuracion, se conecta normal desde `MongoCompas` puedo usarlo normal, pero `Mongose - Express` solo se puede conectar pero no crear la `Collection(tabla)`

```
MongoError: Transaction numbers are only allowed on a replica set member or mongos
    at Connection.<anonymous> (D:\JS\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\pool.js:451:61)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Connection.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at processMessage (D:\JS\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connection.js:451:10)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\JS\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connection.js:620:15)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:271:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:212:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23) {
  ok: 0,
  code: 20,
  codeName: 'IllegalOperation'
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar el código que está generando ese error? Gracias

Comment: @MauricioContreras solo el `user.save()` solo al guardar el objeto

Comment: Eso no lo haces directamente, lo haces dentro de algún método, necesitamos ver todo el conjunto. Por favor leer [mcve]. Ya sé que `user.save()` te da error, pero hay que ver en qué contexto estás usando tu modelo. Sin ver eso es imposible orientarte. Si lo usas dentro de una función, pues copia y pega toda la función. Si es parte de un controlador, pues copia y pega el código mínimo del controlador para poder tener mejor visión de lo que ocurre. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras es todo, esta el rollback porque son varias tablas pero no pasa de crear usuario

Comment: El problema es el que me temía. No puedes usar [*transacciones*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/) en MongoDB a menos que tu instancia de Base de Datos sea un [Conjunto de Réplica](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/) (desde versión 4.2 en adelante) o sea un [Clúster Distribuido](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/) (a partir de MongoDB 4.4). Tu estás tratando de implementar `session` en una base de datos simple (*standalone*), lo cual no es permitido. La solución es usar un Replica Set o un Sharded Clúster, o sino no usar sesión. Saludos